# Style defined in material button is not comprehending with the AppTheme

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

> I chnaged the Apptheme attributes according to the new material guidelines, due to this my material button which I have used in all my project lost their theme colors.

I have tried making custom styles by making the defaults its parent and making them change their primary and secondary colors.

XML file for Button

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/bs_create_business"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/create_business"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey" />
```

styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/foopprimary_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/foopprimary_900</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/foopsecondary_500</item>
        <itemname="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@string/default_font</item>

        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/foopsecondary_500</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/foopprimary_500</item>
    </style>
```

My output is coming like this : 
[image]

Comment: @SumitShukla I have already migrated to androidx

Comment: You are setting the background color with app:backgroundTint="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey" . What is the expected result?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti on removing the background tint I got the outlined button but without the stroke color and without the text(because it will not show on white background).

Comment: @kunalmanocha Not sure about the issue. Check the answer below (too long for a comment. If it doesn't solve I'll update or delete it). There are the default values to check with your colors.

Comment: @SumitShukla thank you so much for your time, but no it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the colors in the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` style just use something lke:

```
  <style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" >
    <!-- Border color -->
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/stroke_color_selector</item>
    <!-- Text color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_selector</item>
    <!-- Background color -->
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/text_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

The default value for the selector are:

StrokeColor:

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_checked="false"/>
  </selector>
```

TextColor:

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
  </selector>
```

Background:

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.08" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
  </selector>
```

Comment: @kunalmanocha Which version are you using of material components library? And try to use a single color (just for a test) instead of a selector. Are the button disabled?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. But according to the material guidelines Material Button should pick coolorprimary as it background and coloronprimary as the text color, but while changing these in the app theme I didn't get the result.

Comment: @kunalmanocha You can also check the [doc of the component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) May be you are referring to the Filled button (style Widget.MaterialComponents.Button),

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! you saved me.